# What is this an example of... 'tongue in cheek' maybe?

Tags: expressions

If i were to call myself a small town doctor, kind of humorously inferring that a small town doctor can be just as good as a big city doctor, would that be an example of "tongue in cheek" ?

Comment: Perhaps you'd be *implying* it, your audience would do the inferring hopefully.

Comment: I don't see the link.

Comment: You might be humorously implying or meaning that a small town doctor can be just as good as a big city doctor. Tongue in cheek is meant when one is trying to avoid being seen as humorous, to avoid showing a smile. I don't see it here exactly.

Comment: Self-deprecating humour?